# How can I split 10 static IP's for 24 computers and still have them in one network?

Tags: networking

What hardware, software and network planning would this require?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer networking questions. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) can give you more details about what types of questions are appropriate to ask here.

Comment: Are those static IPs public? Can you please clarify your question more..

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the 24 computers to share the IPs? Are these servers? If so, are they all identical? Why do you want this?

Comment: That depends what you mean by "static IPs". Where did these IPs come from? From your ISP? from a certain router you're already using? Why only 10?

Comment: What does "have them in one network" mean *precisely*?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an internal network to which the PCs are connected, and assign IPs from a private range, e.g. 192.168.123.0/24 (this can be done automatically using DHCP).
2. Route (NAT) connections to the outside. You can use one static IP for routing everything, or use one IP for the first 3 PCs, the next one for the next 3 etc. Unless you have a good reason to split it up, just route it out via one, otherwise you will have a much more complicated setup.

If you have little to no network experience, get a switch with sufficient ports (at least one more than you have PCs!) and connect it to a router (either dedicated hardware or a PC configured as a router) that can do NAT and will hand out IPs via DHCP. (Alternatively, get an "intelligent" switch with built-in routing capabilities.)

For 24 clients, you may not want to use one of the small home routers, because it could become overwhelmed and behave weirdly (if the load is low, it might work). If you get a PC, you want to put Linux on it, install a DHCP server (dhcpd), and (configure NAT)[http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html].